# Duplicated values in grouped section UITableView swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have created grouped sections in UITableView but values are getting duplicate. How to populate items under each section? Sections I already created. Few Title items are null.

> SectionList --> Title --> Items

#### Like:

- Bir have one item
- Proj Plan have null item
- Proj Ev has three items
- I want to display textField in every section Title.

code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "AppD", withExtension: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonData = try decoder.decode(AppointmentDetail.self, from: data)
                self.AppData = jsonData
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } catch {
                print("error:\(error)")
            }
        }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return  50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return AppData?.sectionList?[section].title
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return AppData?.sectionList?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return AppData?.sectionList?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...


        if let sections = AppData?.sectionList?[indexPath.section].items {
            for item in sections {
                if item.textField != "" {
                    cell.textLabel?.text = item.textField

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can't use the same line of code in both `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection`. And it makes no sense to use a loop in `cellForRowAt`. You need to get the one value specific to the given index path.

Comment: @rmaddy how can I do that can you please guide me? I tried in different ways but not getting in actual. As titles are sections and items are values.

Answer (score 1):

Make changes as below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return AppData?.sectionList?[section].items?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = AppData?.sectionList?[indexPath.section].items?[indexPath.row].textField
    cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

For Adding HeaderView XIB to table view

```
var tableHeaderViewObj : BookNowHotelDetailHeader?
```

inViewdidload

```
tableHeaderViewObj = BookNowHotelDetailHeader(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: (window?.frame.width)!, height: 350))
self.BookNowTV.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderViewObj
tableHeaderViewObj?.parentVC = self
tableHeaderViewObj?.UpdateBookNowHotelData(Obj: hotelDetailObj ?? HotelDetailModal())
```

Comment: make use on indexPath.row = 0 for first row and indexPath.row == AppData?.sectionList?[indexPath.section].items?.count - 1 to get the last row and then apply corner radius. Also change the tableview from plain to grouped.

Comment: Thank you. Let me apply these settings.

Comment: Done it thanks. but need to know cell spacing issue if you know?

Comment: Just a small query actually you helped me a lot in groupTableRoundedCorner thing. I designed it perfectly and working. Is it possible İ can add xib/nib file on top of my section group table but within same tableview? İ am trying but getting display issues in it not properly set.

Comment: @ Yes I have added but it comes on every section header. But I need only once but on top like before section and its must be part of tableview.

Comment: Give me 30 mins I will guide you on it

Comment: Sure Thank you. İf you need screen shot of my tableview do let me know İ will share with you.

Comment: check the edit.. I have added code to add xib to tableview

Comment: not working like that error on last two lines modified it accordingly. Possible İ can share picture with you it makes clear in understanding. İ am using your shared group section tableview.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ss5ypSiYjMgWSeAzgf4NMVBQT7AIO3o9/view?usp=sharing